# What is the diff between directly state update and functional state update in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const getSomeString = () => {
    console.log("1");
    return 'any thing';
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setFoo((foo) => [...foo,  getSomeString() ]);
    // setFoo([...foo, getSomeString() ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I just want to deep dive into setState to have better understand, some one explain that functional state update will use lastest state value, i basically understand.

But as you can see, inside handleButtonClick i have two setFoo function, if i run with first setFoo function, getSomeString will be called twice, but with second setFoo function, getSomeString will be called once, no matter how many items inside foo. I can't explain.

What is the different? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example on some code sandbox online. Cannot replicate it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-r2n6kt?file=src%2FApp.jsx,src%2FApp.css,src%2Findex.css,src%2Fmain.jsx&terminal=dev

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/choosing-right-state-update-method-normal-vs-updates-react-verma-/

Comment: That's just React Strict Mode, it executes the state setter function twice.

Comment: @NickParsons but it only apply for functional state update not update state directly ?

Comment: Yeah, what I mean is that it executes the callback function (the function you pass to `setFoo()` twice) when you're in React Strict Mode. When you don't use the functional setter, then there isn't a function for react to invoke twice anymore.